Custom table of contents in beamer
I am working with the following code as a starting point. It produces a beamer document where the items on the contents page are numbered, and each item number is inside a square. I would like to use this as a starting point to reproduce the output shown in the image below. Basically, I'd like the item number to be spaced equally measured along a curved path from the top of the page to the bottom. The path could be anything, from a circular arc to something more complex (as in the image). The title of each section should also be boxed, as shown. I think this could look quite nice with some tweaking, but I have no idea how to produce the effect in LaTeX. If anyone could offer some assistance, I'd greatly appreciate it.
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[square]

\setbeamerfont{section number projected}{size=\large}
\setbeamercolor{section number projected}{bg=blue,fg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Contents}
\large
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\section{Test}
    some content
\subsection{Test Test}
    some content
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test Test}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test Test}
    some content
\section{Test}
\subsection{Test Test}
    some content
\end{document}



I wouldn't use a toc for this. The beamer toc isn't very flexible. Instead I would use a similar approach as in https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=1987#a2230 but replace the mindmap with markings along a tikz path. (might need two compilations).
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\sectionmax}{\the\beamer@sectionmax}
\makeatother

\AtBeginSection[]{\label{sec:\thesection}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mindtoc}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    remember picture,
    overlay,
    decoration={
      markings,% switch on markings
      mark=between positions 0.2 and 0.8 step 0.6/(\sectionmax-1) with {
        \node[draw,anchor=east,fill=green] {\huge \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}};
        \node[anchor=west,draw,fill=white] {\nameref{sec:\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}}};
      }
    }
  ]
    \draw[postaction={decorate}] (current page.north west) to[out=-70]  (current page.south east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\makeatother
\title{Some Title}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{"Table" of Contents}
    \mindtoc    
\end{frame}

\section{Section One}
\frame{abc}

\section{Section Two}
\frame{abc}

\section{Section Three}
\frame{abc}

\section{Section Four}
\frame{abc}

\end{document}


